# Cómo consumir una api enviando un json en C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest

Necesito consumir una api  debo enviar el siguiente json con application/json utf-8:

```
{
    "tipoSolicitud": 16,
    "motivoSolicitud": 49,
    "tipoContenedorCertificado": 111,
    "txtOtroUso": null,
    "codigoSolicitante": 209299,
    "celularSolicitante": "098665487",
    "rucSolicitante": null,
    "rupSolicitante": null,
    "telefonoDomicilioSolicitante": "05556814",
    "mailSolicitante": "gmail.com",
    "mailAlternoSolicitante": "mail.com",
    "paisDomicilioSolicitante": "239",
    "provinciaSolicitante": "17",
    "cargoSolicitante": null,
    "paisOficinaSolicitante": 239,
    "archivoFoto1": [-1,-40,-1, -37,0, 67, 0, 8, 6,6, 7,6,],
    "ipRegistro": "157.100.173.35",
    "idUsuario": 7
}
```

el campo archivoFoto1 es de tipo Byte.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te consulto, ¿el api la querés consumir desde C#?, es decir, tenes un api en c# y querés consumir otra api desde allí... eso es lo que entiendo que querés hacer.

Si es eso lo que necesitas, necesitas utilizar algo como RestSharp de la siguiente manera:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(urlapi);
 client.UseNewtonsoftJson();

 IRestResponse result = new RestResponse();
result=
client.Execute(RequestHttp.ConfigurarRequest($"inventories/items/lifetime", token));

                var reporteVidaUtilBase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReporteVidaUtilProductoBaseDto>>(result.Content);

 public static RestRequest ConfigurarRequest(string ruta, string token)
        {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(ruta, Method.GET);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return request;
        }
```

Y ese json podes convertirlo en una clase DTO, y con eso podés hacer la petición y mandarla en el body, usando un POST, este ejemplo que te mando usa un simple GET.

Answer (score 0):

Instala el NuGet Newtonsoft.Json, para poder serializar a json los parámetros requeridos. Fíjate que también en el path a la imagen,(supongo que es un string) el cual debes llevarlo a tipo byte ahí te dejo como hacer la conversión que necesitas

```
 using RestSharp;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
 
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("D://pathtoimage/image.bmp");          
        int[] fotoPath = bytes.Select(byteValue =>Int32.Parse(byteValue.ToString())).ToArray();
        var json = new
        {
            tipoSolicitud = 16,
            motivoSolicitud = 49,
            tipoContenedorCertificado = 111,
            txtOtroUso = (string)null,
            codigoSolicitante = 209299,
            celularSolicitante = "098665487",
            rucSolicitante = (string)null,
            rupSolicitante = (string)null,
            telefonoDomicilioSolicitante = "05556814",
            mailSolicitante = "gmail.com",
            mailAlternoSolicitante = "mail.com",
            paisDomicilioSolicitante = "239",
            provinciaSolicitante = "17",
            cargoSolicitante = (string)null,
            paisOficinaSolicitante = 239,
            archivoFoto1 = fotoPath,
            ipRegistro = "157.100.173.35",
            idUsuario = 7
        };
        dynamic stuff1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
       string result = stuff1;
 var clientD = new RestClient("https://ejemplo.com/ejemplo?wsdl");
 clientD.Timeout = -1;
 var requestD = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
 requestD.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 requestD.AddParameter("application/json",result , ParameterType.RequestBody);
 IRestResponse responseD = clientD.Execute(requestD);
 var content = responseD.Content;
```